# Pattern of "you answered my question OK", yet "I will not accept the answer until you reply to my (sometimes numerous) other question(s) in comments"?

Tags: discussion

I've only been on SO since a few months, yet googling could not found a response about this on meta - feel free to downvote/close as duplicate is this is the case. I understand this may be a naive question.

As my experience here build up, I more and more often see a pattern, be it on questions I answer to or not:

- OP post a question,
- someone answer and solve the problem,
- The OP answer in a comment "thanks, it worked!", yet he will not
  accept the answer, nor most of the time even flag is as "helpful" but instead ask another question in a comment, sometimes adding a funny lines such as "I except a response from you" - sic.

**The problem I see with that:
Legitimate questions and helpful responses which could be visible are burried forever. No good. This will not be useful to anybody except the OP.**

How this should be handled?

(I could link to example of this, but I'm sure this is something any half-experienced SO user as come across that already)

(the OP may even accept the answer, an then un-accept it when you stop replying to their new questions hidden in comments - a kind of untold blackmail pattern)

(...and of course the script warning about long comments thread will not stop neither the help-vampire nor the re-whore if they're both desperate)

**As for me, I've already decided my line of conduct: ignore.**

Yet, this is both unpleasant and a waste of time for anyone but the OP. Plain noise. Though this may still be fair questions and valuable reponses that will be no good for anybody, since not noticeable / near to invisible.

This is an obvious help-vampire problem, from users that do not understand how SO works. *Or, and this is very sad and very worse, pretend not to understanding how SO works, and hope they found a rep-whore that would do anything in endless comments to get the rep' from an accepted answer because they perfectly undestand the gamification of the system and its flawns.*

**So what to do / is done about such users and their questions?**

PS:

...And now I after a few month experience here I perfectly understand why some scripts exist to block some users. There is a need for that, but how does SO want or should address this globally.

Comment: Related: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: My day job is 3rd-line support function. This happens all the time to us. Our usual way is to allow a certain amount of scope creep, in the interests of "best efforts", "going the extra mile" etc, but to impose a cutoff then and say : "This has extended well beyond the presenting problem - in the interests of clarity, could you please raise a separate case for the remaining issues". Not sure how that would play in an SO context, but offering it up as an example from a parellel world.

Comment: Plays just fine on Stack Overflow, @angst. Reply to their comment telling them that they need to ask a new question.

Comment: Form the "flag as duplicate" link, that I surely read already, thanks (you come across the syndrome quite early), the accepted answer is "the Help Vampire problem is the idea that some users will continually ask the same tired questions" - yes, I got that. But here the pattern is that the OP ask **another, different, sometimes completely different question(s)** . But if there's no answer else than "help vampires are help vampires and just suck your time", then fine with it. I'll learn how to block some users then.

Comment: @CodyGray I did that once, concluding my side of a very long comment thread by "SO is not a chat room, if you have another question, then ask another question". Reaction? "You don't have to be rude!" + 20 downvotes in a minute (obviously fixed the next day by the voting pattern script). This is quite unpleasant though, and is still a root problem.

Comment: Thanks @Angst. I've done my share of Thier-3/4 support, working on a operating system level developer. We would have horror stories to share around a beer or two. Though, this is paid job, whereas SO is pure volunteer work. And this users behavior is just polluting the whole system.

Comment: Just never make yourself a hostage, you can always outlast their need to get their job done.  Fwiw, after answering questions for a while you can smell them coming from a mile away.  The whiff of garlic is pretty hard to get rid of :)

Comment: @HansPassant So true. I can already smell beforehand the pattern (both from my day to day paid job and SO). Though, I still thing this is a problem for volunteer based time such as SO, that should be seriously addressed. It just degrade the whole SO value.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks, I think I read that already when first coming to SO. Just rode that again. Maybe just a blue feeling from seeing that again and again and again... <sigh>

Comment: @jbm such behaviuir is not uncommon.  Making any kind of protest will result in serial downvotes, managed serial-downvotes, (2 a day until the poster gets tired), to avoid the script, 'hostile, unconstructive, elitist mob downvoter' meta posts and/or 'rude' flags in an attempt to get you suspended.

Comment: "I except a response from you" -> This would almost certainly provoke a response from me. And this response would almost certainly not be the sort of "response" the OP is hoping for. While not exactly rude or offensive as such, it assumes a sense of entitlement and arrogance that is probably, at least partly, at the root of many of these bad questions. How *dare* we not give a prompt answer to a question! Pointing out how inappropriate such a comment is will probably not help, but sometimes it will. I would certainly not help them further, it only feeds the inappropriate attitude.

Comment: Well, leading with "SO is not a chat room" was probably what got you off on the wrong foot. Try, "That's a completely different question, and someone else can probably provide a better answer than I can. You should post it as a new question." or some variation of that. Try to frame it in a positive light, rather than what you are really thinking ("go away, I'm tired of trying to help you"). I get what you're saying, and I'd love to fix it, but there really isn't any way. Half of the time, I'll just ignore the comments altogether. They'll go away after a while to pick on someone else.